# Inject @Parameter in different class in maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am writing a maven plugin and based on my previous experience i know that my mojo class will end up with a bunch of `@Parameter`s to configure it. What I would like to do is instead of having those configuration parameters injected in the mojo class, I would like to have them injected in a second, configuration-only class. Is this possible?

The current way I do it is the mojo class just constructs a Configuration object where it passes all the injected parameters. Something like this

```
@Mojo
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  private MyConfig myConfig;

  @Parameter
  private String myArg1;

  ...

  public void execute() {
     myConfig = new MyConfig(myArg1, myArg2, ...);
  }
}
```

But this is rather ugly. I want the DI to happen directly in *Config*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If MyConfig is a pojo, you can use the `@Parameter` here as well, However, you config will look like:

```
<configuration>
  <myConfig>
    <someField>value</someField>
  </myConfig>
</configuration>
```

The second trick is to use setters, because an @Parameter-annotated field will use the matching public setter, if there is one.

```
private MyConfig myConfig = new MyConfig();

@Parameter
private String someField;

// matching setter for @parameter-annotated field
public void setSomeField( String field )
{
  myConfig.setSomeField( field );
}
```

Comment: IIUC then i would do `@Parameter private MyConfig myConfig;` right? and then on top of that, annotate the parameters in MyConfig?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on the second trick? setting on what, and with the annotation where, in the field or the setter?

Comment: aaah, the second trick is great! i will do that. Thank you Robert

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `MyConfig` POJO as `@Parameter`:

```java
@Mojo
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter
    private MyConfig myConfig;

    ...
}
```

> The rules for mapping complex objects are as follows:
>
> - There must be a private field that corresponds to name of the element being mapped. So in our case the `person` element must map to a `person` field in the mojo.
> - The object instantiated must be in the same package as the Mojo itself. So if your mojo is in `com.mycompany.mojo.query` then the mapping mechanism will look in that package for an object named `Person`. As you can see the mechanism will capitalize the first letter of the element name and use that to search for the object to instantiate.

[*Source*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Complex_Objects)

However, using the `@Parameter` for fields of `MyConfig` has no effect, see [this thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/why-the-defaultValue-is-not-being-injected-in-Parameter-inside-a-complex-parameter-bean-td5835732.html#a5835735).